# Arranging multi-dimensional array populated from different sources

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm populating a multi-dimensional array from different sources.

This is my array structure:

```
$feeds[$source][$indexLoop]["Link"] = $link;
$feeds[$source][$indexLoop]["User"] = $username;
$feeds[$source][$indexLoop]["Url"] = $url;
$feeds[$source][$indexLoop]["Time"] = $created_time;
```

Now, I'm populating the array from the first source, then from the second source after completing the insertion of all entries from the previous source. and so on, with the other sources...

I am thinking of a way of arranging the array by created time (latest to oldest) regardless of the source. What could be the best way to do this?

EDIT: I need the "source" index, because the output layout/design depends on what source it came from. And there's also a part in my app where i only select the array of specific source, like the $feeds[of_source1] only not [source_2] or whatever source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start with just one index, and not two, like this:

```
$userData[$index] = array('Source' => $source,
                          'Link'   => $link, 
                          'User'   => $usernameUrl,
                          'Url'    => $url,
                          'Time'   => $created_time);
$index++;
```

And use that to read in the feeds then you only have to deal with one index. After that you need to sort it. That's easy in PHP:

```
function _compare($data1,$date2)
{
  if ($data1['Time'] == $data2['Time']) return 0;
  return ($data1['Time'] < $data2['Time']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($userData,'_compare');
```

This is a user defined sort: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: I still need the "source" index, because the output layout/design depends on what source it came from. And there's also a part in my app where i only select the array of specific source, like only the $feed[of_source1]

Comment: I will add the source. Done. Selecting a specific source is quite straightforward.

Comment: I mean, how would I select the userData array with a specific source only. Like the $userData array in which source is 1, not 2 or 3

Comment: `foreach ($userData as $data) if ($data['Source'] == 1) {.....}` You did mention 'regardless of the source' in your question.

Comment: Perhaps storing the data in a database is a better idea when the amount of data grows. It can do sorting and selecting more efficiently with large amounts of data.

Comment: the sources were actually 3 different remote databases, which updates regularly, and I need to display the data in one some kind of gallery. More like of a dynamic data feed.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($sources as $key => $source){
  $feeds[$source['date']][$key]['Link'] = $source['link'];
  (...)
}
```

How looks the structure of $source ?